# The dependency isn't installed

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I'm testing my `.deb` package and cannot find out why it doesn't install the dependencies:

The control file's Depends line is:

```
Depends: zend-grid-module, postgresql-8.4, ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
```

And when I run:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i zend-grid-module-test-application_1.0.2-2_all.deb
```

I see:

```
(Reading database ... 25616 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace zend-grid-module-test-application 1.0.2-2 (using zend-grid-module-test-application_1.0.2-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement zend-grid-module-test-application ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zend-grid-module-test-application:
 zend-grid-module-test-application depends on postgresql-8.4; however:
  Package postgresql-8.4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing zend-grid-module-test-application (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zend-grid-module-test-application
```

And after that:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y -f
```

outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  zend-grid-module-test-application
The following packages will be upgraded:
  zend-grid-module-test-application
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/43.8kB of archives.
After this operation, 238kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 25618 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace zend-grid-module-test-application 1.0.2-2 (using .../zend-grid-module-test-application_1.0.2-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement zend-grid-module-test-application ...
Setting up zend-grid-module-test-application (1.0.2-2) ...
```

I don't see the postgresql dependency resolved, though I expect it to be installed with `apt-get install -f -y`

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Is the package you have currently installed (which is the same version number) created without the Depends on postgresql?

Comment: @jordanm: yep... (but it's reproducible on clean as well)

Comment: `apt` only install dependencies if they are available from repository. (also `gdebi` is more helpful to install packages as it checks & downloads (if available) dependencies before installing)

Answer (score 1):

This is the key line of output that explains what's happening:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  zend-grid-module-test-application
```

apt-get has found a different (and newer, or at least the same) version of `zend-grid-module-test-application` to install in some repository you have in `sources.list`. `apt-cache policy zend-grid-module-test-application` will tell you which one.

apt-get then proceeded to install that version (it's newer, after all!) instead of the version you tried with `dpkg -i`. And the one apt-get found does not depend on `postgresql-8.4`.

Most likely, you need to up the version in your `debian/changelog` before running `dpkg-buildpackage`. If you have it installed, `dch` will help you with this.

Comment: "And the one apt-get found does not depend on postgresql-8.4" --- they are. And the changelog version is incremented as expected.

Comment: @zerkms Could you please add `apt-cache policy zend-grid-module-test-application` and `apt-cache show zend-grid-module-test-application | grep Depends`

Comment: it was 3 months ago :-S And I actually don't even remember how I solved it

Comment: @zerkms hah, it showed up on the front page (I guess when Alessandro Meyer added an answer) and I didn't even notice the old date... Though, in the future, when you solve your own issue, please come back an add an answer. Answering your own question is encouraged here.

Comment: oh, got it - the solution was to create a local repository and install from it (it worked). So even though it is a solution for my task - it's not an answer for the question (that's why I didn't put it)

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the version 8.4 of postgres in your repos?

I don't have them with the most recent version of Ubuntu and thats probably why apt-get is not able to resolve.